# ggvis output not appearing in shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I'm at a loss for what is wrong here, and the other threads on Stack in which users discuss their ggvis + shiny woes don't seem to apply, in spite of being very similar.

First, the basic problem is that my ggvis visualization does not appear in the Shiny app. I have another tab in my Shiny app that shows a data table, and that works fine. Also, when I swap out ggvis and use ggplot2 (leaving the rest of the code intact except for using changing to a compatible function in ui.R that calls the visualization), that works fine also. I'm not getting any error messages or warnings in RStudio. I suspect I have some type of problem with the bind_shiny function, but nothing I've tried seems to be working.

**Here is my server.R code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

#import file created by screener.R

final <- read.csv("final-test.csv") 


 # Define server logic required to complete visualization

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

reactviz <- reactive({allviz <- filter(final, DivYield >= input$Yield[1])
allviz <- filter(allviz, DivYield <= input$Yield[2])
allviz <- filter(allviz, PAYOUTRATIO >= input$PayoutRatio[1])
allviz <- filter(allviz, PAYOUTRATIO <= input$PayoutRatio[2])
allviz <- filter(allviz, PriceSales >= input$PriceSales[1])
allviz <- filter(allviz, PriceSales <= input$PriceSales[2])
allviz <- filter(allviz, MarketCapinMil >= input$MarketCap[1])
allviz <- filter(allviz, MarketCapinMil <= input$MarketCap[2])
allviz <- allviz[1:35,]
})

output$visplot <- renderPlot({

allviztip <- function(x) { if(is.null(x))return(NULL) 
  row <- allviz[allviz$id == x$id,c(1,4,8,10,11,12,13)]
  paste0(names(row),":",format(row),"</div>",collapse="<br />")}

reactviz() %>% ggvis(x=~PriceBook,y=~DivYield,key:=~id,size=~MarketCapinMil,shape=~PayoutCat,fill=~PriceSales) %>%
  layer_points() %>% add_tooltip(allviztip,"click") %>% add_axis('x', title='Price/Book Ratio',title_offset=60,properties=axis_props(labels=list(fontSize=12), title=list(fontSize=18))) %>% 
  add_axis("y", title = "Dividend Yield",title_offset=50,properties=axis_props(labels=list(fontSize=12), title=list(fontSize=18))) %>% 
  add_legend(scales="shape", title="Payout Ratio Category") %>% 
  add_legend(scales="fill", title="Price/Sales Ratio", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 100))) %>%
  add_legend(scales="size", title="Market Cap",values=c(1,25,50,100,500,1000,5000,50000,100000,300000),properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 200))) %>% 
  set_options(duration = 0,height="auto",width="auto") %>%
  scale_numeric(property="fill",range=c("lightblue","darkblue")) %>%
  bind_shiny("visplot","visplot_ui") 

})

output$stockdata <- renderTable({

tableviz <- filter(final, DivYield >= input$Yield[1])
tableviz <- filter(tableviz, DivYield <= input$Yield[2])
tableviz <- filter(tableviz, PAYOUTRATIO >= input$PayoutRatio[1])
tableviz <- filter(tableviz, PAYOUTRATIO <= input$PayoutRatio[2])
tableviz <- filter(tableviz, PriceSales >= input$PriceSales[1])
tableviz <- filter(tableviz, PriceSales <= input$PriceSales[2])
tableviz <- filter(tableviz, MarketCapinMil >= input$MarketCap[1])
tableviz <- filter(tableviz, MarketCapinMil <= input$MarketCap[2])
tableviz


})



})
```

**Here is my ui.R code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Visual Stock Screener"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("MarketCap",
                  "Market Capitalization (in Tens of Millions)",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 60000,
                  value = c(100,30000)),

      sliderInput("Yield",
                  "Dividend Yield:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 1,
                  value = c(.04,.5)),

      sliderInput("PayoutRatio",
                  "Payout Rato:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 5,
                  value = c(0,.5)),


      sliderInput("PriceSales",
                  "Price/Sales Ratio:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 25,
                  value = c(0,7)),


      sliderInput("PriceBook",
                  "Price/Book Ratio:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 30,
                  value = c(0,4))

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tab",
                  tabPanel("Plot",ggvisOutput("visplot"),uiOutput("visplot_ui")),
                  tabPanel("Data",tableOutput("stockdata")),
                  tabPanel("Documentation",includeHTML("screener-documentation.html"))
                  )


  )
)))
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong and why my visualization isn't appearing?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `final-test.csv` please

Comment: hi Pork Chop,

thanks for your reply. i've uploaded the final-test.csv file here: http://simitpatelonline.com/wp-content/uploads/final-test.csv

please let me know if there is anything else i can do to help.

Comment: You don't need `renderPlot` when working with *ggvis* plots - see [this recent discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/-hJSr9NiYck) for an example.

Comment: @simitpatel I am having the same problem. In my case I have no uiOutput and am simply using bind_shiny and ggvisOutput in my ui.R file.  I would add that all of my UI elements are loading and any data generated from my global.R file is loading but no data is loading from server.R, even unrelated data like a table isn't loading.  In addition no breakpoints are able to be set in my server.R file. when I remove the ggvisOutput from from ui.R everything works fine and server.R is able to run. Any luck on your end for this?

Comment: @DonaldVetal this was  some months ago so i'm not entirely sure about all that's happened in my code since, but i know now it is working. i'm not using reactviz() in my server.R. i also removed the `)}` after the plot and BEFORE the output table in my server.R, so that everything only gets closed at the end. sorry if this is not clear, i need to stay within the character limit i have here on SO. hope that helps.