# All values in column used for 'key' property should be unique, but some values are duplicated

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have an application built in R using the shiny and ggvis libraries finally working -- sort of. One issue I'm running into is that the `add_tooltip` function results in the following warning:

`All values in column used for 'key' property should be unique, but some values are duplicated.`

I'm using a column named `id` to serve as the key for my dataframe, and I've run `na.omit` to eliminate NA values and the `duplicated` function to test for duplicates in that column; it confirms that each value is unique. The values in that column were generated using the `sample` function, with replacement set to FALSE. I also generated it by setting `df$id <- 1:nrow(df)` though the warning persists.

As it is a warning I can still run the application, but when I click on a tooltip, I get a whole string of values replete with NAs. below is the code for the function that builds' the tooltip's content and the ensuing ggvis code that calls the function.

```
allviztip <- function(x) { if(is.null(x))return(NULL) 
row <- allviz[allviz$id == x$id, ]
paste0(row$Ticker)}

allviz %>% ggvis(x=~PriceBook,y=~DivYield,key:=~id,size=~MarketCapinMil,shape=~PayoutCat,fill=~PriceSales) %>%
  layer_points() %>% add_tooltip(allviztip,"click") %>% add_axis('x', title='Price/Book Ratio',title_offset=60,properties=axis_props(labels=list(fontSize=12), title=list(fontSize=18))) %>% 
  add_axis("y", title = "Dividend Yield",title_offset=50,properties=axis_props(labels=list(fontSize=12), title=list(fontSize=18))) %>% 
  add_legend(scales="shape", title="Payout Ratio Category") %>% 
  add_legend(scales="fill", title="Price/Sales Ratio", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 100))) %>%
  add_legend(scales="size", title="Market Cap",values=c(1,25,50,100,500,1000,5000,50000,100000,300000),properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 200))) %>% 
  set_options(duration = 0,height="auto",width="auto") %>%
  scale_numeric(property="fill",range=c("lightblue","darkblue")) }) %>%    bind_shiny("visplot","visplot_ui") `
```

Any ideas on how I can get the tooltip working properly?

Comment: I actually saw this when you posted a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957676/ggvis-output-not-appearing-in-shiny-application).  It happens when you do a bunch of data manipulation steps, and then finish with the line `allviz <- allviz[1:35,]`.  If `allviz` doesn't have 35 rows then R helpfully adds a bunch of rows until it does.  I believe this causes the error you are asking about.